# Bugzilla Testopia Installation in Ubuntu

Tags: bugzilla

I have installed bugzilla and testopia on ubuntu but i am not able to open  bugzilla GUI.

### After running ./checksetup.pl the message i get is

""Now that you have installed Bugzilla, you should visit the 'Parameters'page (linked in the footer of the Administrator account) to ensure it is set upas you wish - this includes setting the 'urlbase'option to the correct URL.""

When i try to open it from browser ,i get the coding page but not the GUI of bugzilla.

Please help.

Regards,
Ruchi

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix your webserver settings,

If you use Apache2, add the following settings to the  /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file, by default it is an empty file.

```
Alias /bugzilla/ /var/www/bugzilla/
<Directory /var/www/bugzilla>
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
    Options +Indexes +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.cgi
    AllowOverride Limit
</Directory>
```

Dont forget to save the configuration!

ctrl + o

Then exit:

ctrl + x

Finaly restart the Apache2 webserver

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

It should work now :)